# CreateUser through controller FosUserBundle

Tags: forms, orm, fosuserbundle, symfony4

Ill try to add some data to database and in the same controlle create user by userManager aswell. Ill made something like this, there is no error nothing when i submit this form which i rendered page just reload and this not even redirecting to route, nothing. 
Any idea what`s wrong ?

***EDITED***

My controller look right now like:

```
/**
     * @Route("/dystrybutor/pracownicy/add", name="dystrybutor_pracownicy_add")
     */

    public function new(Request $request)
    {


    $pracownik = new Pracownik();

    $form = $this->createForm(PracownikType::class, $pracownik);

        return $this->render('dystrybutor_pracownicy/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));



        $form->handleRequest($request);





    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $id = $this->getUser()->getDystrybutorId();

        $username = $form["username"]->getData();
        $password = $form["password"]->getData();
        $email = $form["email"]->getData();



        $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setLocked(0); 
        $user->setEnabled(1); 
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->addRole("ROLE_PRACOWNIK");



                try {


            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                'error', 'Wystąpił błąd przy udodawaniu użytkownika!'
            );
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dystrybutor_pracownicy'));

        }  


        return $this->redirectToRoute('dystrybutor_pracownicy');
    }
    }
```

But still ORM not add user to database, nothing happend. Here what i use in this controller:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Entity\Dystrybutor;
use App\Entity\Clients;
use App\Entity\Pracownik;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use App\Form\PracownikType;
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;
```

And this is how i build my own formType, i am sure the problem is that i not submiting it properly and controller not handle it.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Hasła muszą być takie same.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Hasło'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Powtórz hasło'),
            ))
        ->add('email')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Dodaj pracownika'));
}
```

Comment: After when i create system user I wanna get id of this user and add "pracownik" and connect with relation to user passing the id to "Pracownik" Entity and other data from form. But fos user not creating... there is no eny succecs masseges nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/new", name="new_user")
 */
public function addUser(UserManagerInterface $userManager, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) // use dependency injection as recommended by symfony
{
    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $user->setPassword('1312adaSz');
    $user->setEmail('eadas@emadi.com');
    $user->setUsername('user6');
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->setRoles(array_merge($user->getRoles(), array_diff(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'], $user->getRoles()))); // roles stored as array

    $entityManager->persist($user); // add user to queue
    $entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: I edited my question, look how it looks all controller.

Comment: ok your example works, but i think it is something with handle request...

Comment: @flow, you have return before handleRequest

Comment: LOOOOOOOL ! :( insane... works perfect :P is any good code editor for symfony ?

Comment: If we are here, can you tell me how to pass some success or error messages after submited the form ?

Comment: for example if i submited and i return false that i can return it false with some error information... ? or success after all...

Comment: Great! You know how to leave values in form after returning error ?